# Vagrant set default share permissions

Tags: virtualization, permissions, virtualbox, vagrant

When running a vagrant instance the project folder is mounted on `/vagrant` automatically. However is mounted with the following permissions

```
# ll -d /vagrant
drwx------ 1 vagrant vagrant 612 Jun 13 14:41 /vagrant/
```

I need it to be mounted with (at least) 0770 but I can't find how. If I run the mount command I see this output

```
# mount
v-root on /vagrant type vboxsf (uid=1000,gid=100,rw)
```

I've tried both `chmod` and `chown/chgrp`, but they won't work on that mounted folder so my apache user can't access that folder. I [read in Vagrant manual](http://vagrantup.com/v1/docs/config/vm/share_folder.html) that I can change owner and group but it doesn't mention nothing about permission.

How can I do that?

Another option could be switch to NFS but in this way it won't work on Windows platforms and it need to edit local `/etc/exports` file and it would require root privileges and also it's pretty annoying, so I'd prefer to not make this change.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Solved with this line in my Vagantfile, for v1.3.2 and later:

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", :mount_options => ["dmode=777","fmode=666"]
```

Syntax before 1.2 version:

```
config.vm.share_folder("v-root", "/vagrant", ".", :extra => 'dmode=770,fmode=770')
```

Credits: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1434884

For Vagrant 1.2 the right syntax was:

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", :extra => "dmode=777,fmode=666"
```

Credits: [Aal](https://serverfault.com/questions/398414/vagrant-set-default-share-permissions#comment569936_399230)

For v1.3.2 and later the 'extra' flag on synced folder was changed to 'mount_options'. The options need to be in an array with each option as a separate string ( as opposed to both options being in a single string in previous versions )

Comment: Dunno why, but I need a slightly different syntax: `config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", :extra => "dmode=777,fmode=666"`

Comment: +1 Aal and +1 Fabio: share_folder is pre-Vagrant v1.2, synced_folder is Vagrant v1.2 and after. I use puphpet.com to generate my Manifest but had to do this adjustment in the Vagrantfile.

Comment: config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", :mount_options => ["dmode=777,fmode=666"] worked for me on v1.3.2.

Comment: In Vagrant 1.4.3 the syntax is a bit different yet again. The following change to Vagrantfile worked for me: config.vm.synced_folder "#{folder['source']}", "#{folder['target']}", id: "#{folder['id']}", type: nfs, mount_options: ["dmode=777","fmode=666"]